# Programatically check in javascript if socket.io and jQuery were defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I'm building a JS script that can be embedded in any web site. This script relies on jQuery and socket.io so I need a way to check if these 2 libraries (jQuery & socket.io) have been already included in the master page where the script will be embedded.

If they have been defined all's good. If not, I need to include them to be able to use them later. Any idea how this can be accomplished in pure Javascript?

Pseudocode of the JS widget:

- is jQuery installed?
  => No: install
- is socket.io installed? 
  => No: install
- do the magic stuff

Any tips will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for the presence of their global variables.

```
if (!("jQuery" in window)) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = --jQuery URL--;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

And the same for socket.io

Comment: Thanks Christoph.  Could you pls elaborate on socket.io, how the if should look like ?

Comment: I think it would be `!("io" in window)` from what I can see in the socket.io docs